# mData error when trying to use datatables

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am trying to use datatables, but keep getting an mdata error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
>
> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

Here is my html and jq. I have the same number of ths and tds. What am I missing?

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#seats').DataTable( {
          "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
      } );
    </script>
```

```html
   <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="seats">
   <thread>
    <tr>
     <th>Seat Number</th>
     <th>Full Name</th>
     <th>Status and Level</th>
    </tr>
   </thread>
                        <tbody>
                           <tr><td class='one'>1</td><td class='two'>NAME1</td><td class='three'>...</td></tr>
                           <tr><td class='one'>106</td><td class='two'>NAME2</td><td class='three'>...</td></tr>
                           <tr><td class='one'>107</td><td class='two'>NAME3</td><td class='three'>...</td></tr>
                           <tr><td class='one'>113</td><td class='two'>NAME4</td><td class='three'>...</td></tr>
    </tbody></table></div>
    </body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ordering by column with index `3` ie `4th` column

Since you don't have a `4th` column, datatable is giving you the following error.

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#seats').DataTable( {
            "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]
        } );
        });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-hover" id="seats">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Seat Number</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Status and Level</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                       <tr><td class='one'>1</td><td class='two'>NAME1</td><td class='three'>...</td></tr>
                       <tr><td class='one'>106</td><td class='two'>NAME2</td><td class='three'>...</td></tr>
                       <tr><td class='one'>107</td><td class='two'>NAME3</td><td class='three'>...</td></tr>
                       <tr><td class='one'>113</td><td class='two'>NAME4</td><td class='three'>...</td></tr>
</tbody></table></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

## For updated question

- You haven't closed the `$(document).ready` function correctly
- You have used `thread` instead of `thead`

Make those changes, and the code will start working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#seats').DataTable({
    "order": [
      [1, "desc"]
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <table class="table table-hover" id="seats">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Seat Number</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Status and Level</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class='one'>1</td>
            <td class='two'>NAME1</td>
            <td class='three'>...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class='one'>106</td>
            <td class='two'>NAME2</td>
            <td class='three'>...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class='one'>107</td>
            <td class='two'>NAME3</td>
            <td class='three'>...</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class='one'>113</td>
            <td class='two'>NAME4</td>
            <td class='three'>...</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! I have changed that but I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: @an_owl          i have updated the answer. please have a look. if you find the answer helpful, please upvote it. it would help me too.

Comment: Thanks! That spelling mistake really killed me... (ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the script tag.
Also don't forget a datatable needs to have both thead and tbody if I'm not mistaken.
Here you go. Please mark answer if you accept.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#seats').DataTable( {
            "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
        });
});
        </script>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-hover" id="seats">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Seat Number</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Status and Level</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       <tr><td class='one'>1</td><td class='two'>NAME1</td><td class='three'>...</td></tr>
                       <tr><td class='one'>106</td><td class='two'>NAME2</td><td class='three'>...</td></tr>
                       <tr><td class='one'>107</td><td class='two'>NAME3</td><td class='three'>...</td></tr>
                       <tr><td class='one'>113</td><td class='two'>NAME4</td><td class='three'>...</td></tr>
</tbody></table></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Sorry my copy/paste skills are weak. I have verified the script tag is closed in the file. I will update the post to reflect that. Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed you have a tbody but not a thead. I think you have to have both in a datatable!

Comment: I have the thead before the tbody. I call the thead after I call the table and I call the tbody after I end the thead.

Comment: I meant thread instead of thead but i see someone else wrote that down in an answer so all good now.